# html Map not working in IE

Tags: css, dictionary, hyperlink, area

For some reason, Image Map is not working (partially) in IE.

For e.g. in this code, the first link `MapMap2` is working but the lower one `MapMap` is not working in IE.

Any idea?

### HTML

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_10 prefix_1 suffix_1">

            <img name="home001_r2_c1" src="images/ndm-head.jpg" width="1100" height="491" id="home001_r2_c1" alt="" border="0"  usemap="#MapMap2"/>
             <map name="MapMap2" id="MapMap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="51,46,443,207" href="index.html" />
             </map>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="masonry" role="main">

      <div class="lower-body"><img name="home001_r2_c2" src="images/home.jpg" width="1100" height="1219" id="home001_r2_c2" alt="" border="0" usemap="#MapMap"/>
         <map name="MapMap" id="MapMap">
         <area shape="rect" coords="53,1117,147,1150" href="index.html" />
         <area shape="rect" coords="150,1113,321,1149" href="C4P.html" />

        </map>

      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use two map id's. Change the first Map's id from MapMap to MapMap2 and see if that works.